# А как добраться на shorcodes до объекта со значениями

Tags: wordpress

Есть поле "comment", у которого два значения: "Одобрено" и "Не одобрено", которое создано при помощи плагина ACF. В административной панели, если набираешь "Не одобрено", на странице записи будет написано значение "Одобрено". Я так понимаю тут проблема заключается в объекте, в котором лежат два значения и wordpress берет первое значение несмотря на то, что ты выбираешь второе.

Как на shorcodes написать то значение, которое нужно?

```
Комментарий администратора: [acf field="comment"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Требуется развернуть задачу.

Непонятно, поле "comment" в какой сущности (это пост, таксономия, произвольный тип записи)?
Далее, Вы во фронтэнде или бакэнде проверку как прикрутили (хук или код в файле)?

Естественно, если делать произвольные поля и их не читать и не проверять, то результат будет не предсказуемым и произвольным.